# How to make tabhost/ tabwidget displayed in vertical style in Android Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I would like to make my tab display vertically in left side. I use

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in tabwidget. If I include this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
```

in my manifest file, it can just displayed fine. However, because I have a code that connected to internet database need to set the version to "3", so when I change the version to 3, the tab cannot be displayed.

```
<TabHost   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent" 
               android:layout_width="380dip"
               android:layout_weight="0" 
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="#ffe185"
               />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

match_parent did not become available until API 8.  Try replacing with fill_parent.  If you only go back to API 4, you can use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).